# Why is this printing the memory location of array elements of second and third arrays?

Tags: arrays, c

```
char model[10][15] = {"Honda","Audi","Ferrari","Jeep","Toyota","Bugatti","Ford","Jensen","Porsche","Suzuki"};
int price[10][15] = {750000,650000,950000,300000,900000,1000000,400000,750000,300000,800000};
int remain[10][15] = {3,4,5,3,3,7,8,2,1,2,2};

for(i=0;i<11;i++){
            printf("\n%s\t %d\t %d\t",model[i],price[i],remain[i]);
        }
```

I tried all sorts of things but nothing worked... I'm a new C programmer (just jumped from JAVA)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are declaring your arrays wrong.

```
char *model[11] = {"Honda","Audi","Ferrari","Jeep","Toyota","Bugatti","Ford","Jensen","Porsche","Suzuki"};
int price[11] = {750000,650000,950000,300000,900000,1000000,400000,750000,300000,800000,9000};
int remain[11] = {3,4,5,3,3,7,8,2,1,2,2};
```

Answer (score 0):

`model` is an array of 10 arrays of 15 `char`.

Therefore `model[i]` is one of those 10 arrays; it is an array of 15 `char`.

When an array is used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` or as a string literal used to initialize an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. Therefore, using `model[i]` as an argument to `printf` passes a pointer to the first element of the array `model[i]`.

With `%s`, `printf` expects a pointer to a `char`, and it prints the string of characters it finds starting at that location in memory. So passing `model[i]` passes a pointer which works with `%s`.

`price` is an array of 10 arrays of 15 `int`.

Therefore `price[i]` is one of those 10 arrays; it is an array of 15 `int`.

Passing `price[i]` to `printf` passes a pointer to the first element of the array `price[i]`.

With `%d`, `printf` expects an `int` value, not a pointer, so passing `price[i]` does not work.

Instead, you want `price` to be an array of 10 `int`. Then `price[i]` will be an `int`, not an array of `int`. To do that, change the definition:

```
int price[10] = {750000,650000,950000,300000,900000,1000000,400000,750000,300000,800000};
int remain[10] = {3,4,5,3,3,7,8,2,1,2,2};
```

Then passing `price[i]` to `printf` will pass an `int`, not a pointer.

Comment: Woah i didn't think i'd get a reply so soon. Thanks a lot